# How to go to up form in vxml

Tags: goto, vxml

I want to create vxml file for that process.

1). Press 1 for **confirm**.

2). Press 2 for **next**.

3). Press 3 for **back**.

but this function isn't working, what can do for it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.1">

<form id="1">
    <field name="F_1">
        <prompt>
            Your choices are
            <break strength="medium" />
            press one or say shatner, press two or
            say Nimoy, press three or say terminal Thilina.
        </prompt>

        <option value="1" dtmf="1"></option>
        <option value="2" dtmf="2"></option>
        <option value="0" dtmf="3"></option>

        <filled>
            <prompt>
                You said <value expr="F_1"/>
            </prompt>
        </filled>
    </field>

    <filled>
        <if cond="F_1 == '1'">
                <prompt>
                    Thank 
            </prompt>
        <elseif cond="F_1 == '2'" />
                <goto next="#2"/>
        <elseif cond="F_1 == '3'" />
            <goto next="#0"/>
        <else />
            <goto next="#1"/>
        </if>
    </filled>
</form>
<form id="2">
    <field name="F_2">
        <prompt>
            Your choices are not
            <break strength="medium" />
            press one or say shatner, press two or
            say Nimoy, press three or say terminal Sampath.
        </prompt>

        <option value="2" dtmf="1"></option>
        <option value="3" dtmf="2"></option>
        <option value="1" dtmf="3"></option>

        <filled>
            <prompt>
                You said <value expr="F_2"/>
            </prompt>
        </filled>
    </field>

    <filled>
        <if cond="F_2 == '1'">
                <prompt>
                    Are you get value
            </prompt>
        <elseif cond="F_2 == '2'" />
                <goto next="#3"/>
        <elseif cond="F_2 == '3'" />
            <goto next="#1"/>
        <else />
            <goto next="#1"/>
        </if>
    </filled>
</form>
</vxml>
```

1). how I solve this? any error in if loop? How can I find my code has error?

2). How to check vxml correct format?

3). What kind error it have? There are I looking main propose is **Press 3 for back** not working. then there second form in can't go to first form. How I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. It isn't clear what you mean by this question as you haven't fully described the behaviors you are experienced versus the desired behaviors.
2. VoiceXML syntax can be validated against the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.dtd).  This won't verify your logic, just your element and attribute usage.
3. Is 3 not working in the second form only?  You currently have the 3 DTMF key mapped to the value of 1, which plays "Are you get value"

Comment: I ran your XML through a validation web site.  The only error it detected was invalid form ids.  You are using numbers, not valid labels. Without more information, it is difficult to provide additional help.

Comment: There are go to second form can't go to first form that is not working.